# Javascript: innerHTML doesn't always update

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, timing, watch

I got this function, which gets fired every second by setInterval

```
function updatetimer() {
    if (timesec==0) {
        if (timemin==0) clearInterval(interval);
        else {
            timemin--;
            timesec=59;
        }
    }
    else timesec--;

    document.getElementById('timeleft').innerHTML=timemin+':'+timesec;
}
```

You'd expect it to update the element named timeleft's innerHTML with the new time every second. But for some reason it doesn't, or sometimes it does. It might have something to do with all the other coding, as there's a lot of setTimeout and DOM-stuff going on.

If this is supposed behavior, could you please point out another way of doing this.

Thanks in advance, Locercus

Answer (score 0):

Event scheduling with `setTimeout` and `setInterval` is a *best effort* model. If you schedule an interval to run every 1000ms it could run much later if there are other events being processed.

This is why it's typically a bad idea to implement a *clock* with a `setInterval` that triggers every second. Your clock will always be slow.

Comment: I'd agree if it were for some sort of software, but I'm making a little minigame here, so it doesn't really matter.